# What does のに mean at the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 忘れてて良いのに

I understand this as: "You should forget about it"

But what does のに do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

のに is a conjunction that corresponds to "even though ～" or "despite ～".

`(clause A)のに(clause B)` = `although A, B`.

Unlike けど, it often (but not always) is followed by something regrettable/disappointing. [Examples on JGram](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=noni).

The latter clause is often omitted, and it implies the reality is something regrettable and contrary to the Clause A.

`～のに。` = `although ～, (something contrary)`, `A, but...`, `I wish ～`.

So 忘れてて良いのに means "You could have left it (although, in reality, you recalled and mentioned it)".

Examples:

> - こんなに美味しいのに。 It's really delicious (and I wonder why you don't want to eat it)!
> - そんなに賢いのに。 You are such a smart boy (and I don't understand why you did such a silly thing)!
> - もっと頑張れば良かったのに。 You should have worked harder.
> - 空を飛べたらいいのに。 I wish I could fly.

See also:

- [How and when to use のに(=noni) - Maggie Sensei](http://maggiesensei.com/2012/06/20/how-and-when-to-use-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%ABnoni-request-lesson/)
- [Meaning and level of 死ねばいいのに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/181/5010)

Answer (score -1):

I can suppose the following situation.

A helped B out of his (her) hard situation.

B is one of the best A's friends, and A wants to be kind without being patronizing.

However, every time when B meets A, B shows his (her) thanks.

Then A says "忘れていいのに"

The full sentence could be "まだあなたは感謝を忘れないんですね。私は忘れていいと思っているのに（どうぞ忘れてください）。" = "You still owe a huge debt to it、but I sincerely want have you forget it."

"忘れていいのに・・・" implys such nuans.

Comment: あなたの一つ前の回答のところで既に「わかりました、迷惑ならやめます」とコメントさせていただき、同時に今までのあなたの回答へのEdit（私による編集が最新のもののみですが）を全てRollback(元に戻す)させていただきましたが、まだいけないでしょうか。。。ところで「せいをだす」は「 **勢**を出す」じゃなくて「 **精**を出す」です・・・

Comment: ①[Editを拒否する姿勢はこのサイトの基本方針に反します](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing)。②何にせよPSにあるような議論は[meta site](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/)かチャットでやるべきです。