# Formation of word "何となく"

Tags: meaning

I think, the word "何となく" means as below

> somehow or other; for some reason or another;

However, how it has been formed so that it means like above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

何となく is made up of:

- 何【なん】と: contraction of...

  - 何【なに】: question-word "what"
  - と: quotative particle "(call/say) that"
- なく: adverbial form of i-adjective ない ("not be"); "not being, without"

As a whole it means "without 'what'", or in more understandable English "without naming what (it is)", thus comes to represent a feeling that you can't pinpoint the specific reason.

Note that this phrase is already an idiom, with an undivided accent なんとなく{LHHHL} instead of etymological なんと{HLL}なく{HL}.

Similar constructions:

- [それとなく](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/131791/meaning/m0u/) "without (pointing) 'that'" → "implicitly; subtly"
- 幾度／何度となく "without 'how many times'" → "countless times"
- [～ともなく](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50260/7810) "without any specific" ([a JLPT N1 grammar](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F-tomonaku/))