# What is the function of「のに」at the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I stumbled across this sentence in manga

> 直さないと前に進まないのに...!!

This is the speaker's internal monologue. She was regretting what she told her friend earlier.

I still can't figure out the function of「のに」in this sentence after I read this [article](https://maggiesensei.com/2012/06/20/how-and-when-to-use-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%ABnoni-request-lesson/). This particle has many functions. I'm not sure what is the correct one. It's hard for me to wrap my head around this particle.

I first thought it means "despite the fact that" or "even though," but it didn't fit the context because it doesn't make sense to say "Even though if this problem isn't fixed then I can't move forward..."

It seems to me that none of the other meanings in the linked article fits the context. I might be overthinking.

What's the role of「のに」in the sentence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does のに mean at the end of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42408/what-does-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab-mean-at-the-end-of-this-sentence)

Comment: @Shurim I already checked. It didn't help.

Comment: I know only 2 uses of 「のに」. Please check  [here](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/how-to-express-aims/#3)  or [here](https://marshallyin.com/courses/n4-grammar-course/lessons/n4-grammar-rule-13/). Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Your explanation "She was regretting what she told her friend earlier." does not give us a clear connection to that sentence. We still need more context to know why you feel "it didn't fit the context". Maybe a screenshot of the page would help.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the sentence appeared after the character couldn't fix something.
Here, the sentence means that "I wouldn't be able to go forward if I don't fix this, but I just can't!" with the "just can't fix" part abbreviated.

It has the same meaning as 「直さないと前に進まないのに、直せない」.

Sorry my English is not good enough to give you a phrase that represent the meaning  of のに here, but I hope you can get what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably simplest to think of this のに as just "but". The clause after "but" is omitted.

> 直さないと前に進まないのに...!!
> [This/It] won't move forward if I don't fix it, but...!!

There is probably something that prevents the speaker from fixing "it".

<sub>(I said "probably" because you provided almost no context. I imagined the context based on your translation attempt, but there can be other possible translations such as "You should've fixed it if you wanted to move forward!" Please at least explain who is trying what. Also note that the subject of 進まない should be an inanimate object because this person is not saying 進めない.)</sub>