# What is the meaning of "いいのにな"?

Tags: translation

I was just wondering what is the translation for "いいのにな" in English. I'm kind of confused about that "のに".

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/35715/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/181/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11426/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you gave the whole sentence, but you can probably take it as, 'it would good if ... but this is (unfortunately) not the case', which expresses a wish or regret.

For example,
おばあちゃんがいるといいのにな

I wish grandma was here.

The な gives the sentence more feeling and makes it sound like the speaker is talking to themselves.

http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/skills/grammar/sentences/?grammarid=367